# How do I get LongVarchar out param from SPROC in ADO.NET 2.0 with SQLAnywhere 10?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlanywhere

I have sproc 'up_selfassessform_view' which has the following parameters:

```
in ai_eqidentkey SYSKEY
in ai_acidentkey SYSKEY
out as_eqcomments TEXT_STRING
out as_acexplanation TEXT_STRING
```

-  which are domain objects - SYSKEY is 'integer' and TEXT_STRING is 'long varchar'.

I can call the sproc fine from iSQL using the following code:

```
create variable @eqcomments TEXT_STRING;
create variable @acexamples TEXT_STRING;
call up_selfassessform_view (75000146, 3, @eqcomments, @acexamples);
select @eqcomments, @acexamples;
```

- which returns the correct values from the DB (so I know the SPROC is good).

I have configured the out param in ADO.NET like so (which has worked up until now for 'integer', 'timestamp', 'varchar(255)', etc):

```
SAParameter as_acexplanation   = cmd.CreateParameter();

as_acexplanation.Direction     = ParameterDirection.Output;
as_acexplanation.ParameterName = "as_acexplanation";
as_acexplanation.SADbType      = SADbType.LongVarchar;

cmd.Parameters.Add(as_acexplanation);
```

When I run the following code:

```
SADataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I receive the following error:

```
Parameter[2]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.
```

Which (I suppose) makes sense...

But the thing is, I don't know the size of the field (it's just "long varchar" it doesn't have a predetermined length - unlike varchar(XXX)).

Anyhow, just for fun, I add the following:

```
as_acexplanation.Size = 1000;
```

and the above error goes away, but now when I call:

```
as_acexplanation.Value
```

i get back a string of length = 1000 which is just '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0...' (\0 repeated 1000 times).

So I'm really really stuck... Any help one this one would be much appreciated.

Cheers! ;)

Tod T.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not passing the parameter data type and letting ADO.NET figure it out on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the size to -1?

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222661/can-i-return-a-varcharmax-from-a-stored-procedure/265975#265975) answer.